# using v-for for rendering

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7

i am build a laravel vue appliction and i want to render my categories from my categoriescontroller

heres my categorycontroller

```
public function index()
    {
        // geeting all the categories
        $categories = Category::all();
        return response([ 'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($categories), 'message' => 'Retrieved successfully'], 200);
    }
```

heres my category.vue file

```
<tbody>
                        <tr v-for="category in categories.data" :key="category.id">
                        <td>{{ category.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
                        <td>11-7-2014</td>
                        <td><span class="tag tag-success">Approved</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
```

here also is my method in my category.vue file for loading my categorys

```
 loadCategory(){
                axios.get("api/category").then(({ data }) => (this.categories = data));
                
            },
```

now i dont have any errorrs but its not rendering my categories either. please in need of assistance

Answer (score 1):

since you're destructing the response inside the callback parameters `.then(({ data })` you should directly render `categories` without `.data` field :

```
<tr v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
```

Answer (score 1):

as you sending the data from laravel using api resource the actual data is loaded inside a data property. so you should extract it like this in the axios call

```
loadCategory(){
                axios.get("api/category").then(({ data }) => (this.categories = data.categories.data));
                
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

yes i just quickly want to clearify , just incase someones sees this issue both answers from @Boussadjra Brahim and @sazzad was helpfull . so what i did was

first i took @Boussadjra Brahim  suggestion and changed this

```
 <tr v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                        <td>{{ category.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
                        <td>11-7-2014</td>
                        <td><span class="tag tag-success">Approved</span></td>
 </tr>
```

then i still got errors until i tried @sazzad suggestion but took out the `.data` attribute giving me this

```
 loadCategory(){
                axios.get("api/category").then(({ data }) => (this.categories = data.categories));
                
            },
```

hope this helps someone also thanks again